# Testing Authlogic Remember Me with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, cucumber

Has anyone tried to test the Authlogic "Remember Me" functionality with Cucumber?  I am not sure how to get webrat to "close a browser" to test persistence.

Only thought is maybe it requires selenium?  Is there a way to do without?

Answer (score 0):

Webrat communicates with Rails app more directly than a browser(like Selenium does). I would make a custom matcher like:
(Then) I should be remembered by the application

And then I would check the db or the session, depends how the authlogic handles this feature.